# Is there any way to create a key binding in eclipse RCP that works regardless the focus?

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, key-bindings

I am developing a RCP application in eclipse. I need to create a key binding to do some action, but regardless the current focus.

In other words, I need to create a key binding that is listening all time, no matters which part of the application yo uare using or which window have the current focus.

For example, given a window with a menu (`File`) and two options (`Open` and `Exit`). `Open` opens a dialog and Exit closes the application. There is also a key binding (`ctrl+1`) that executes the `Exit` button. What I want is to be able to close the application with `ctrl+1` even if I have the focus on the dialog displayed by `Open`.

## What I have tested

Now I have a RCP application that has a ke binding (ctrl+1) to the Exit button, but when I do ctrl+1 while the focus is on the dialog displayed by open, the key binding does not work.

Here are the handlers.

```
// Handler for the Open button
public class OpenHandler implements IHandler {

    ...

    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final ExecutionEvent auxEvent = event;
        HandlerUtil.getActiveShell(event).getDisplay().asyncExec((new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                MessageDialog.openWarning(HandlerUtil.getActiveShell(auxEvent),"wrong","no");
            }
        }));
        return null;
    }

    ...

}


// Handler for the Exit button
    public class ExitHandler extends AbstractHandler {

          public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
            HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(event).close();
            return null;
          }
    }
```

And here the manifest with the key bindings etc.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>

   <extension
         id="application"
         point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications">
      <application>
         <run
               class="de.vogella.rcp.commands.first.Application">
         </run>
      </application>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectives">
      <perspective
            name="RCP Perspective"
            class="de.vogella.rcp.commands.first.Perspective"
            id="de.vogella.rcp.commands.first.perspective">
      </perspective>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <command
            defaultHandler="de.vogella.rcp.commands.first.commands.ExitHandler"
            id="de.vogella.rcp.commands.first.commands.Exit"
            name="Exit">
      </command>
      <command
            defaultHandler="de.vogella.rcp.commands.first.commands.OpenHandler"
            id="de.vogella.rcp.commands.first.commands.Open"
            name="Open">
      </command>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            allPopups="false"
            locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu">
         <menu
               id="fileManu"
               label="File">
            <command
                  commandId="de.vogella.rcp.commands.first.commands.Exit"
                  label="Exit"
                  style="push"
                  tooltip="Exits the application">
            </command>
            <command
                  commandId="de.vogella.rcp.commands.first.commands.Open"
                  label="Open"
                  style="push"
                  tooltip="Opens">
            </command>
         </menu>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
      <key
            commandId="de.vogella.rcp.commands.first.commands.Exit"
            contextId="org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window"
            schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"
            sequence="M1+1">
      </key>
   </extension>

</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key bindings don't generally work when a dialog is open.

It is possible to write dialogs where they do work, but you can't add this to existing dialogs.